# create a new list using function

Tags: python, list

```
def over(xs,ys):
```

how do i make a new list with the first value of xs, then the first value of ys, then the second value of xs, second value of ys, and so on.

example

```
([1,2,3], ["hi", "bye",True, False, 33]) ===> [1, "hi", 2, "bye", 3, True, False, 33]
```

Answer (score 4):

On Python 2.X:

```
>>> data = ([1,2,3], ["hi", "bye",True, False, 33])
>>> [x for t in map(None, *data) for x in t if x is not None]
[1, 'hi', 2, 'bye', 3, True, False, 33]
```

On Python 3.x:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> data = ([1,2,3], ["hi", "bye",True, False, 33])
>>> [x for t in zip_longest(*data) for x in t if x is not None]
[1, 'hi', 2, 'bye', 3, True, False, 33]
```

#### Answer to comment question:

You should absolutely positively have no hesitation about using itertools / zip_longest. However, if you want to have a curiosity:

```
def oldMapNone(*ells):
    '''replace for map(None, ....), invalid in 3.0 :-( '''
    lgst=len(max(ells, key=len))
    return list(zip(*[list(e) + [None] * (lgst - len(e)) for e in ells]))

data = ([1,2,3], ["hi", "bye",True, False, 33])
print([x for t in oldMapNone(*data) for x in t if x is not None])
# [1, 'hi', 2, 'bye', 3, True, False, 33]
```

Works on either Python version. I cannot recommend that in preference to itertools version however.

Comment: +1 I didnt know map could do that.

Comment: It is deprecated and no longer works in Py3 but I always thought that was cool. Same as `izip_longest` as long as the `None` is used instead of a function. Kinda obtuse...

Comment: Indeed it is cool. I though that the first param to map should be a function.

Comment: in python 3 is there any way to solve this problem without import something, just use function

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> l2
['hi', 'bye', True, False, 33]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> while l1 or l2:
...     if l1: l1.pop(0)
...     if l2: l2.pop(0)
... 
1
'hi'
2
'bye'
3
True
False
33
```